# Espresso Unit Testing NullPointerException

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin

I'm have a problem with my unit testing.
when set favorite value from unit testing, but return always NullPointerException.

this is my repository:

```
class FakeFilmRepository(
    private val remoteDataSource: RemoteDataSource,
    private val localDataSource: LocalDataSource,
    private val appExecutors: AppExecutors) : FilmDataSource {

    override fun setFilmFavorite(film: FilmEntity, state: Boolean) =
        appExecutors.diskIO().execute { localDataSource.setFilmFavorite(film, state) }}
```

And this is my unit testing:

```
class FilmRepositoryTest {

@get:Rule
var instantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

private val remote = mock(RemoteDataSource::class.java)
private val local = mock(LocalDataSource::class.java)
private val appExecutors = mock(AppExecutors::class.java)
private val filmRepository = FakeFilmRepository(remote, local, appExecutors)

private val movieResponses = DataDummy.generateRemoteDummyMovies()
private val movieId = movieResponses[0].id
private val movieCastResponses = DataDummy.generateRemoteDummyCasts(movieId)

@Mock
private lateinit var observer: Observer<FilmWithCast>

@Test
fun setFavoriteFilm() {
    val dummyFilmWithCast = Resource.success(DataDummy.generateDummyFilmWithCasts(DataDummy.generateDummyMovies()[0], false))
    val film = MutableLiveData<Resource<FilmWithCast>>()
    film.value = dummyFilmWithCast
    `when`(filmRepository.getFilmWithCasts(movieId)).thenReturn(film)

    val castResource = film.value
    if (castResource != null) {
        val filmWithCast = castResource.data
    
        if (filmWithCast != null) {
            val filmEntity = filmWithCast.mFilm
            val newState = !filmEntity.favorite
            filmRepository.setFilmFavorite(DataDummy.generateDummyMovies()[0], newState) //ERROR NULL
        }
    }

    verify(observer).onChanged(dummyFilmWithCast.data)
} }
```

Result ERROR NULL:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.pamungkasrizall.films.data.FakeFilmRepository.setFilmFavorite(FakeFilmRepository.kt:188)
at com.pamungkasrizall.films.data.FilmRepositoryTest.setFavoriteFilm(FilmRepositoryTest.kt:115)
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You should setup diskIO() to return an actual value, something like:

```
when(appExecutors.diskIO()).thenReturn(someActualValue)
```

Without setup, diskIO() returns default value which is null, and invoking a function (execute) on null generates an exception.

Comment: Thanks @opel for your answer, my problem has been fixed. with : doCallRealMethod().`when`(local).setFilmFavorite(DataDummy.generateDummyMovies()[0], false)
        local.setFilmFavorite(DataDummy.generateDummyMovies()[0],true)
        
        verify(local, times(1)).setFilmFavorite(DataDummy.generateDummyMovies()[0],true)